# How to trigger Worksheet_Change from OLEOjects?

Tags: vba, excel, combobox

I want the macro to run automatically when the combo box value in worksheet change but I did not find any code that can fix my code.

Here is the code

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

With Me.CBbox
    If Not Intersect(Target, ActiveSheet.Range(OLEObjects.LinkedCell)) Is   Nothing Then
        Call Macro
    End If
End With

End sub
```

Comment: That is a `SelectionChange` event, not a `Change` event.

Comment: I already tried in change, also does not work @rory

Comment: Is your combobox an ActiveX component? I.e. can you attach code to it and use the `ComboBox_Change` event? Does it **have** to be the `worksheet_change` event that is triggered?

Comment: @SteveES yes it works. I call the macro in the CBbox_Change. Thank you. I thought that everything change must be under worksheet.

Comment: @SteveES how to put multiple range in change event, eg: `Range("E10:E20")` . I tried multiple ways, but it still does not work

Comment: @nx170 1) I don't quite understand what you are trying to do. 2) You should ask that as a separate Question, not as a question in a Comment.

Comment: @SteveES Okay sorry, my bad.

Comment: @nx170 No need to be sorry, you'll get better help by posting a new Question and it will be easier to find for others with the same question :)